# Show percent in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I do a histogram in percentages (which works well) but when I try to  print the value of the percentages, the scale of the y axis is not right anymore.

The code for the histogram in percentages (which works well) is the following :

```
data_impact_final %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time_to_treat_month)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),binwidth=6) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEn72.jpg)

However, when I try to print the percentages on the graph using stat_bin, the scale of the y axis is not right anymore. Here is the code I use to print the percentages :

```
data_impact_final %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time_to_treat_month)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),binwidth=6) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=6, geom='text', color='white', aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))),position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAK8v.jpg)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the labels are placed at `y=..count..`. To solve your issue use `y=..count../sum(..count..)` in `stat_bin` too.

**UPDATE** As of `ggplot2 3.4.0` the dot-dot-noation (`..count..`) was deprecated in favor of `after_stat()`.

Making use of `ggplot2::mpg` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),binwidth=6) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))), binwidth = 6) +
  stat_bin(
    binwidth = 6, geom = "text", color = "white",
    aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count)), 
        label = scales::percent(after_stat(count / sum(count)))),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: How to make it work when grouping by a factor?

Comment: Hi @Julien. When grouping by a factor things get slightly more complicated. Here we have to take account of the grouping similiar to a `group_by` + `summarise`. See e.g. my answers on [Percentage labels per x-axis group in stacked bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717600/percentage-labels-per-x-axis-group-in-stacked-bar-plots/71717714#71717714) or [ggplot geom_bar plot percentages by group and facet_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68227541/ggplot-geom-bar-plot-percentages-by-group-and-facet-wrap/68227836#68227836).