# Displaying the distribution of the seperate bins in a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to compare the distribution of a categorical variable (two levels) between three subgroups of my dataset, using a barplot (in ggplot2).

When I try to display the percentage it shows the percentage relating to the whole dataset (cf. [my output as picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehoje.png)). How can I make it display the share within each bin/ group?

This is my code:

```
#data
structure(list(Attrition = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), Datasets = c("Training", "Training", 
"Original", "Training", "Original", "Training", "Training", "Original", 
"Training", "Training", "Testing", "Original", "Original", "Training", 
"Original", "Original", "Original", "Training", "Training", "Original", 
"Original", "Original", "Original", "Training", "Training", "Original", 
"Original", "Original", "Training", "Original", "Original", "Original", 
"Training", "Original", "Testing", "Training", "Testing", "Testing", 
"Training", "Training", "Training", "Training", "Training", "Original", 
"Original", "Original", "Testing", "Original", "Original", "Training", 
"Testing", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Testing", 
"Original", "Original", "Original", "Training", "Testing", "Original", 
"Training", "Original", "Original", "Training", "Testing", "Original", 
"Testing", "Original", "Original", "Testing", "Testing", "Original", 
"Training", "Original", "Training", "Testing", "Original", "Original", 
"Original", "Testing", "Original", "Training", "Training", "Original", 
"Training", "Original", "Training", "Original", "Original", "Training", 
"Original", "Original", "Training", "Training", "Original", "Testing", 
"Training", "Training", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Original", 
"Training", "Original", "Original", "Training", "Original", "Original", 
"Testing", "Original", "Training", "Original", "Original", "Original", 
"Training", "Testing", "Original", "Original", "Testing", "Original", 
"Training", "Training", "Training", "Training", "Testing", "Testing", 
"Training", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Original", 
"Testing", "Testing", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Testing", 
"Original", "Original", "Original", "Original", "Training", "Training", 
"Training")), row.names = c(1916L, 2345L, 512L, 1804L, 712L, 
1510L, 1485L, 887L, 2292L, 1646L, 2741L, 279L, 233L, 2238L, 97L, 
925L, 832L, 1898L, 1677L, 1256L, 21L, 1390L, 805L, 1755L, 2256L, 
663L, 782L, 300L, 1630L, 68L, 165L, 1237L, 2031L, 834L, 2853L, 
2353L, 2856L, 2813L, 2434L, 1701L, 1693L, 2130L, 2340L, 433L, 
1042L, 350L, 2649L, 278L, 710L, 1666L, 2567L, 45L, 1091L, 1333L, 
632L, 2547L, 1022L, 1120L, 788L, 2376L, 2740L, 474L, 2456L, 667L, 
1130L, 2022L, 2715L, 1011L, 2910L, 1181L, 301L, 2707L, 2779L, 
642L, 2028L, 611L, 1781L, 2721L, 1233L, 19L, 553L, 2643L, 638L, 
1881L, 2264L, 341L, 2091L, 451L, 2220L, 835L, 1360L, 1859L, 342L, 
943L, 1965L, 2293L, 543L, 2782L, 2254L, 2242L, 1403L, 979L, 779L, 
222L, 2425L, 908L, 34L, 1551L, 432L, 1053L, 2687L, 787L, 1682L, 
860L, 567L, 595L, 2273L, 2720L, 1132L, 1288L, 2788L, 231L, 2145L, 
2368L, 1945L, 2225L, 2849L, 2578L, 1956L, 408L, 741L, 871L, 859L, 
927L, 2677L, 2654L, 151L, 1006L, 904L, 2683L, 799L, 1387L, 1019L, 
1457L, 2192L, 1942L, 2062L), class = "data.frame")

#plot

ggplot(data = dist.atr) +
  
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Datasets, fill = Attrition),
         
         position = "fill") + 
  
  geom_text(aes(x = Datasets, fill = Attrition, label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))),
            
            stat = "count",
            
            position = "fill",
            
            vjust = 1.5,
          
            size = 6,
            
            colour = "white") +
  
  labs(title = "Distribution of Attrition Variable",
       
       subtitle = "by dataset split", 
       
       x = "Datasets",
       
       y = "Distribution")
```

I don't know how, but I think I need to change this part: "label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count","

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: The most simple approach would be to compute the counts outside of `ggplot` but if you want to compute the percentages on the fly then you could do `geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(count / tapply(count, x, sum)[x])), ...)`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717600/percentage-labels-per-x-axis-group-in-stacked-bar-plots/71717714#71717714

Comment: Yes of course! I'm sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow... lmk if what I added is what you meant :)

Comment: @stefan Thank you for your help! But it tells me that arguments don't have the same length...

Comment: Everything fine. Asking a duplicate isn't bad. On the contrary, it helps to find the the already existing answers. I just checked based on your the data you provided. Doing `geom_text(
  aes(x = Datasets, group = Attrition, label = scales::percent(
    after_stat(count / tapply(count, x, sum)[x])
  )),
  stat = "count",
  position = "fill",
  vjust = 1.5,
  size = 6,
  colour = "white"
)` worked fine for me. Perhaps that issue is/was that I missed to specify the `x` and `group` aesthetics or a paranthesis at the wrong place.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I think the issue was that I put "fill = Attrition" and not "group = Attrition".